# Functions without an elementary primitive

Tags: analysis

$Li(x)$ Is a non elementary function being the primitive of $\frac{1}{log(x)}$. I know also that the primitive of $e^{x^2}$ Is not elementary and I know that Gauss calculated some definite integral involving that function.  Are there other examples of functions which doesnt have an elementary primitive? How to prove that a function has not an elementary primitive?

Comment: The Risch - algorithm can decide whether a given function has an "elementary" antiderivate. In theory , this problem is undecidable , but apart from pathological cases , it always works.